# "undefined reference" to Virtual Base class destructor

Tags: c++, abstract-class, undefined-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I have some experience with Java, and am now doing a C++ course. I wanted to try writing an interface, but I have run into some trouble with destructors which I have not been able to resolve, even with the help on the Internet... Here's my code:

```
    class Force {

    public:

    virtual ~Force();
    virtual VECTOR eval(VECTOR x, double t);

};

class InvSquare : public Force {

    public:

    InvSquare(double A) {

        c = A;

    }

    ~InvSquare(){};

    VECTOR eval(VECTOR x, double t) { // omitted stuff }

    private:
    double c;

};
```

I have tried to declare a virtual destructor for the base class, and a non-virtual one for the derived class, but I get an error saying "undefined reference to `Force::~Force()'". What does it mean, and how can I fix it?

Forgive me if this is a silly question!

Thank you very much for your help,
noctilux

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You've declared the destructor, but not defined it. Change the declaration to:

```
virtual ~Force() {}
```

to define it to do nothing.

You also want to make all the functions in the abstract interface *pure virtual*, otherwise they will need to be defined too:

```
virtual VECTOR eval(VECTOR x, double t) = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- that's one problem less...

Comment: A, so called,  C++ interface is a class in which all methods are pure virtual, all but the destructor?